# How to speed up iteration?

Tags: python, pandas

I got this code, and I want to iterate over a csv file with ~100000 columns.

This script do run very slowly to iterate over that number of columns.

Do any of you have a possible solution to speed up my code?

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math    

a=pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep = ';', skiprows=[1,2],usecols = [1,2,3,4],dtype=float, decimal=',')
v1 = (math.sqrt(2)/math.sqrt(3))
v2 = (1/math.sqrt(6))
v3 = (1/math.sqrt(6))
v4 = (1/math.sqrt(2))
v5 = (1/math.sqrt(2))

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

for i in range(len(a)):
    id = ((v1*a.iloc[i,1])-(v2*a.iloc[i,2])-(v3*a.iloc[i,3]))
    iq = (v4*a.iloc[i,2])-(v5*a.iloc[i,3])
    ax.scatter(id,iq)
    print(i)

plt.show()
```

This is a look into my  csv data:

```
time;A;B;C;D
(s);(mV);(mV);(mV);(mV)

0,00000000;5,43279200;-19,49701000;5,09095300;1,83738200
0,00010000;6,84287600;-17,72677000;12,59309000;2,53937200
0,00020000;4,02270800;-20,08302000;-1,94725900;2,77743900
0,00030000;4,37675500;-17,84275000;9,07703500;2,30741000
0,00040000;5,66475400;-18,90490000;12,70907000;-6,98937800
0,00050000;2,61872800;-18,43487000;4,73690600;-2,28299400
0,00060000;4,26077400;-17,01868000;12,59309000;-5,81125600
0,00070000;4,02270800;-17,61079000;17,98926000;-6,51935100
0,00080000;2,02661500;-17,01868000;10,48102000;-5,93334100
0,00090000;3,08265200;-15,72458000;17,28116000;-7,45940700
0,00100000;-0,20144060;-18,08082000;3,68086900;-6,63533100
0,00110000;3,43669900;-7,34953000;17,75119000;-6,28738900
0,00120000;1,67867200;-17,25674000;16,81724000;-4,40117200
0,00130000;-0,67146870;-15,84056000;13,41716000;-6,28738900
0,00140000;-0,43340250;-14,90050000;15,05921000;-0,51886220
0,00150000;-3,13759000;-16,78672000;3,44890700;-0,04883409
0,00160000;6,25686700;-12,06812000;17,51923000;-3,57709700
```

Comment: Are you sure it's Pandas that's taking a long time here, and not Matplotlib? The Matplotlib documentation says to use `plot` rather than `scatter` for simple cases where every marker should have the same size and colour. What happened when you tried to profile the code? When you say "very slowly", just how long? How long do you think is reasonable for this task, and why?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `a` please? 100000 columns or rows?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks! Yes, matplotlib is the reason for.  Very Slowly means more than 20min +.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

The OP is having trouble reading the CSV file, presumably because of the 2-row header and the slightly unusual separator (and the decimal comma).

Here is a way to read such a file:

```py
a = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), sep=';', decimal=',', header=[0,1])

>>> a
     time         A         B          C         D
      (s)      (mV)      (mV)       (mV)      (mV)
0  0.0000  5.432792 -19.49701   5.090953  1.837382
1  0.0001  6.842876 -17.72677  12.593090  2.539372
2  0.0002  4.022708 -20.08302  -1.947259  2.777439
...
```

To drop the units from the columns (facilitate indexing):

```py
a.columns = a.columns.droplevel(1)
```

Then, in the expression below, replace `a[1]` by `a['A']`, etc. to get:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    v1 * a['A'] - v2 * a['B'] - v3 * a['C'],
    v4 * a['B'] - v5 * a['C'],
])
```

**Original answer**

While the time spent computing your `x` and `y` values, if you do it right, is negligible (10 ms per million rows), the time plotting all the points is not.

For 100K points, it's still tolerable, but if you have millions, consider using [`hist2d()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html), or Seaborn's [`jointplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) instead. Bonus, the latter also plots the marginal distributions:

```py
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(1_000_000, 4)))
v1 = np.sqrt(2/3)
v2 = 1 / np.sqrt(6)
v3 = v2
v4 = 1 / np.sqrt(2)
v5 = v4

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    id_=v1 * a[1] - v2 * a[2] - v3 * a[3],
    iq=v4 * a[2] - v5 * a[3]),
)
# timeit of this gives 9.89 ms ± 9.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
df.plot.scatter('id_', 'iq')
plt.show()
# timeit (makes multiple plots) and indicates:
# 2.91 s ± 11.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Instead:

```py
%%timeit
sns.jointplot(
    data=df, x='id_', y='iq', kind='hex',
    marginal_kws=dict(bins=50),
    joint_kws=dict(bins=50),
)
plt.show()
# indicates:
# 852 ms ± 1.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have the problem left, that i dont get my data frame from the csv fitted properly to that dict. I add my csv data to the question post.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use loop, `scatter` can take array-like as argument:

Sample:

```
# a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100000, 4)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
>>> a
              A         B         C         D
0      0.797683  0.819883  0.190643  0.838554
1      0.494024  0.757094  0.863671  0.492803
2      0.935607  0.272122  0.834900  0.707307
3      0.635601  0.329287  0.703526  0.984984
4      0.117422  0.583254  0.399773  0.182749
...         ...       ...       ...       ...
99995  0.182855  0.960854  0.531180  0.242445
99996  0.632885  0.607970  0.043772  0.080374
99997  0.570511  0.214377  0.063418  0.810628
99998  0.401211  0.713925  0.573271  0.500783
99999  0.028511  0.470635  0.315194  0.019288

[100000 rows x 4 columns]
```

Code:

```
x = (v1*a[1]) - (v2*a[2]) - (v3*a[3])
y = (v4*a[2])-(v5*a[3])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: this only plots the first line of the data frame, but not the whole df. I need to print all data. Or did i missunderstand your code?

Comment: Pandas, like Numpy that underlies it, can "broadcast" mathematical operations - multiplying an entire column by a constant at once, adding two columns element-wise, etc. The code here will produce two `Series` (representing columns of data), which Matplotlib accepts and uses to scatter-plot every point.